# Error: Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config. Resolve or resync (no repositories in build gradle app)

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I am trying to setup Firebase in my android project. I am getting this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDw5b.png)

**Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.**

Been looking for fixes online, most of them are removing jcenter() in build.gradle file. I **don't have jcenter()** or any other repository in my build.gradle.

I have tried to follow manual from Firebase but then things get even more messy.
Is there maybe problem with my android studio version?
I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4.
Android gradle plugin version:7.0.4
Gradle version: 7.0.2

Heres my **build gradle project:**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

****Build gradle module (app):****

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.autentikacija"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, i searched and i found the steps to follow on [the website of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file). I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: It's great that you shared your source. However, it would be better to include the actual answer from this article.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

actually you can change  the compileSdk to 31, or you can keep it 32 but you need to change the Gradle Wrapper to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

that workes with me, I hope it will with you also

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem. I tried nearly 2 days to solve it. Just remove your
`testImplementation 'junit:junit:'`
from build.gradle(module) dependency and sync again. This is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the compileSdk from 32 to 31. No need to remove any dependency.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

> testImplementation 'junit:junit:'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I Have tried all the solutions above.
The problem with people like me was not updating the software.

> Click Help > Check for Updates > Update the software

*It will take time and the whole software will be updated*

- it will ask for Restart >for safety (Build a new project ) > Get the
  Gradle version upgraded (it will take time)> check for connecting
  FIREBASE.

> file> project structure> upgrade 7.x.x

Mine got connected.
Hope this helps